# How can I connect a local Arduino to my Google Assistant without relying on cloud services?

Tags: smart-home, google-assistant, arduino, ifttt, smart-assistants

I want to make a product, which consists of an Arduino connected to my local Blynk server (an application which allows me to control my Arduino using my smartphone).

I want it to connected to my Google Assistant on my phone. To do that, I can use IFTTT and Webhooks, but I don't want to rely on cloud-based servers — I want to do this so that my users can control their IoT devices even when they're offline but still connected locally to the hardware via their own home network (their router).

**How can I create a local server which connects services like Google Assistant to my Arduino (with Blynk) as a replacement for Webhooks and IFTTT, so that I don't have to rely on cloud services?**

Comment: You realize that Google Assistant is a cloud service?

Comment: Google Assistant can still do things offline such as calling someone using your voice, i just want to do the same thing but instead of calling someone i want to read, get,post or post something, it also shows what it can do when your offline, I want to add something to that list

Comment: This is probably unsupported.  If you want to control things on a purely local network, you'll likely need to build your own solution perhaps by adapting open source starting points.  Also note that a local solution requires your phone to be on wifi and not a mobile network, unless your Arduino is sitting on a network which allows inbound connections, something most wisely do not.

Comment: I do want to use it when my phone is connected to the local network, and I can use it using a mobile network by port forwarding,I can create a new inbound rule to access it from another network

Answer (score 6):

Cloud-based services are unlikely to offer much 'local-lan' functionality without some competitive pressure. Specifically, a lan implementation requires a local hub. That could be the service's native hub, or it could (in your case) be a 3rd party hub. Generally, LAN functionality seems to be supported only where there is a WAN fallback (to hide the local network or not problem), and only between a vendor's mobile app and own hub hardware.

You may be able to intercept Google Assistant on the actual mobile device, and have it interact with your own mobile app - anything else will require a complicated chain of interactions (if it's possible at all).

Comment: I want to create my own ifttt local server, I am willing to do it, tell me how to, and how to add a custom device to the devices list in Google Assistant